# Не находит обработчик аутентификации. Когда он есть. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Пишет ошибку:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Bearer",...)?
```

Код в Startup:

```
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
```

Код в контроллере, если вдруг в нем ошибка:

```
        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(InputModel inputModel, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(inputModel.Email, inputModel.Password, inputModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View("Index");
        }
        //}

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Как исправить?

Comment: `services.AddAuthorization` вижу, а где `services.AddAuthentication`?

Comment: @tym32167, Походу в этом и была проблема

Comment: Конечно, это же вам прямым текстом написано в ошибке `Did you forget to call AddAuthentication()?`

Comment: @tym32167, Я, я, я слепой... Извините

Comment: @tym32167, а не подскажите, какая авторизация используется по стандарту? То у меня используется на странице проверка на авторизацию:@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)), но после добавления services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme), проверка не срабатывает